# Unset all session variables - local websites

Tags: php

Why do we have to unset all sessions variable after log out,why not just unset the session variable used to check if a user is logged in .I ask because I have 4 sites on local host,if a user is logged in on the four site in the same browser  and i destroy the session when a user logs out of one, automatically the user would be logged out of the remaining 3 because session destroy destroys all sessions.

Comment: Why do you think it' necessary to unset all SESSION variables on logout?

Comment: 4 sites all using the same session for one user ? Is that intensional?

Comment: Yes I mean when we have alot of session variables why not just unset the session variable that checks if user is logged in.

Comment: Please explain _in your question_ how you are doing the ___unsetting of all sessions___ I think we, definitley me, may be confused by what you mean by this.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  the  it's not  the same session variable..what I mean is if  I destroy session on logout, since I am on local host using wamp , the user will be logged out of all site because session destroy destroys all session variable.

Comment: I think @d0uph1x means why all session variables are unset rather than why he should unset all sessions. If this is the case, the answer should be simple -- if you host multiple sites from the same server, all the sites will be using the same session unless you call `session_name()` in the sites. However, note that this may be insecure since different sites can access each other's data directly.

Comment: If a user logs in I set session variables for user_ID,useename,fname,lname.But when checking if a user is logged in, I only check if user_ID is set with Php isset(). So if a user logs out all I do is    unset($_SESSION['user_ID']);

Comment: @SOFe what do you suggest

Comment: Are you calling session_destroy() etc.?

Comment: No..Actually the four sites have different session variable , but I only unset the session variable I use to check login for each site when a user logs out..Please can I get your Facebook username ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using the same session for four different sites, unless you *want* them to be linked, and all clear at the same time, etc.

Your problem is that in development, all the sites are on one domain, and the same cookie is being used for all four sessions.

The way to handle this cleanly is using [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name), which allows you to have completely different sets of session data for each site, by sending different cookies to the browser for each one. Then running `session_destroy()` would only clear the details for the current site, not the other three sites.

Note also that this issue would almost certainly not arise on a production site, because each site would be on a different domain, meaning separate cookies, and therefore separate sessions.

If you *do* want all four sites to share the same session for some reason, *and* can because they all run on the same domain in production, then you are quite right, you could just unset individual variables to save states like "logged into site A as user X, but not logged into site B". This is, however, very unusual, and you probably just want to use `session_name()` so that your sessions are separate even on development.

Comment: Thanks alot..I'll use the session_name();

Comment: please can I add you on Facebook